# Solve simultaneous equation with multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am confused on how I solve the following simultaneously. 
\begin{align*}
3x+y & = 7\\
xy & =-6
\end{align*}

I already made $y$ the subject, but what do I do after that?

Comment: Substitute your expression for $y $ into the other equation.

Comment: Sure, so y=7-3x but then when I substitute I get 7x-3x^2 = -6

Comment: Which makes sense. How many solutions do you think there are? Hint think about the graphs.

Comment: You can transform the equation $7x - 3x^2 = -6$ into the form $3x^2 - 7x - 6 = 0$, then factor to find the roots.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Solve for $y$ in the second equation to get $$y= \frac{-6}{x} = -6x^{-1}$$

Then plug that value for $y$ into the first equation and solve for $x$